# vue mixin doing an axios call and setting data

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have to hit an api and set the get some values from response and set it to the global mixin so that its avaialble to all components.. this is kind of an intialisation logic and api call has to run only one..

```
import Axios from 'axios'

let updatetime
function fetchData () {
  console.log('fetchData invoked')
  return Axios
    .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
    .then(response => {
      updatetime = response.data.time.updated
    })
}
fetchData().then(respons => { console.log('INSIDE---' + updatetime) })

const myMixin = {
  data () {
    return {
      time: 'invalidTime'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('old time' + this.time)
    this.time = updatetime
    console.log('new Time' + this.time )
  }
}

export default myMixin
```

I was hoping I can do a axios call outside [so that the axios doesnt run each time for a component] and set the value back to mixin.. I kind of want that axios call to be synchrnous since without this value other components wont work..

But the mixin methods runs before the axios finishes..
what is the right of doing this?

Comment: How about a computed property that `Promise`s to return the data once resolved (falls back to some default values while ajax is taking place)? Or, have a look at [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).

Comment: can you plz provide some code?How to update this value once the promise is resolved?

Comment: Are you using Vuex store in the project?

Comment: A mixin is a code that runs once for each component. That's not what you want, even though what you want can be achieved with a service-like mixin. Two good ways of achieving this would be to use Vuex (a module specialized in sharing data across all app) or placing the results in some global object and make it available everywhere as `this.$yourVariableName`. Could you provide a [mcve] with what you have now?

Comment: Yup..i am using it

Comment: If you're using Vuex, just pick one particular component that does the call (fetches data) and once the result is returned place it in Vuex. From there you can share it across all app using `...mapGetters` from Vuex, in component's `computed`. If you want to make it available without having to specify it in `computed`, you can use a global object.